# Why was Shakuntala Devi's husband not gay in the film?

Tags: character, historical-accuracy, shakuntala-devi

The film *Shakuntala Devi* is based on [the real-life personality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuntala_Devi), and in real life it was all over the news that her husband was gay after she mentioned it during the release of her book *The World of Homosexuals*.

But apparently, in the film, they claim that it was all a lie and her husband was not gay. On what basis does the film contradict public knowledge in this significant matter? Is there any legitimate proof for her husband not being gay in the film or in reality? Did the filmmakers have additional information for making this claim or did they take creative liberties with this? Or is it intentionally contradicting reality?

Comment: As an LGBT individual myself, I'm curious to know what you would accept as "proof" of him being gay.

Comment: @F1Krazy self acknowledgment or wife interview where she agree she lied. Right now it can be just a coverup in film, it was widely known fact with no backlash from husband about his sexuality then why now

Answer (score 4):

The [Hindustan Times](https://m.hindustantimes.com/books/essay-vidya-balan-s-shakuntala-devi-biopic-suggests-the-genius-lied-about-her-husband-s-sexuality-to-sell-her-book/story-WaxBKNj2pKiBec9Z6QrQHJ.html) has an article on this, with a quote from “Nayanika Mahtani, who has researched the film, and co-written the script”:

> This was exactly how it was related to us by her daughter, Anupama Banerji. Shakuntala Devi, during her various discussions with her daughter, would say that she made up the story about her husband Paritosh being gay as she was constantly challenged on her credentials for writing a book on the subject of homosexuality that was such a taboo during those days.